# Excel: count number of conditionally formatted rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I have an excel sheet in which I apply conditional formatting on two columns. The row is only highlighted if the cells in that row meet the condition. Specifically, I want to highlight rows where the content in one column begins with a specific letter and the number in another column is greater than 500. I use this function:

```
=AND($B2 > 500, SEARCH("A", $C2)=1)
```

The correct rows are highlighted, but is there a way to count the number of highlighted rows?

I tried using the COUNTIF function:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$C$50, AND($B2 > 500, SEARCH("A", $C2)=1))
```

But it returns 0. Any suggestions?

I am using Microsoft Excel 2016 for Mac

Comment: link-only answer: [How to Count the number of cells with a specified background color (using VBA)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2815384/count-the-number-of-cells-with-specific-cell-color-by-using-vba)

Comment: Alternative, hacky answer: add your AND condition as a new column, count the number of TRUEs in that column.

Comment: Unfortunately, that just counted all the rows in the range. I think the problem is that none of my methods is treating the highlighted rows as colored. It's treating it as blank.

Answer (score 2):

Using your specific conditional formatting formula requires an array entered solution:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Array enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in `D2` (don't forget to remove the `{` and `}`):

```dart
{=SUM((B2:B50>500)*IFERROR((SEARCH("A",C2:C50)=1),FALSE))}
```

As this is an array entered formula, an array is generated for each of the ranges `B2:B50` and `C2:C50`, with the array values being the results of the respective comparisons for each row.

The key thing to understand is that, when multiplied, a `TRUE` value is converted to a `1`, and a `FALSE` value to a `0`. Thus the array generated by the multiplication of the two arrays will contain elements with a value of `1` if and only if *both* the `B` column is greater than 500 and the `C` column starts with an "A". (Otherwise, the element value will be a `0`.)

Summing the array leads to the count of the rows where both conditions are true.

---

Rather that checking to see if the index of the first letter "A" found of the value in the `C` column is "1", a better solution would be to check if the first character is an "A", directly:

```dart
{=SUM((B2:B50>500)*(LEFT(C2:C50,1)="A"))}
```

With the formula in this new format, and being aware that the `COUNTIFS()` function can use wildcards, it becomes obvious that a non array entered alternative solution is:

```dart
=COUNTIFS(B2:B50,">500",C2:C50,"=A*")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still returned 0. I think my rows are not being recognized as being highlighted even though they are highlighted.

Comment: @cslearner88 That is not possible. If the conditional formatting formula you use to highlight the cells is the same as what you posted in your question (`=AND($B2 > 500, SEARCH("A", $C2)=1)`), and the `Applies to` range begins with `$B$2`, this answer *will* work. Please double check if the conditional formatting formula is indeed as you specified, and that the `Applies to` range starts at that cell. If you've *manually* highlighted the cells, then of course this solution won't work. You can test this by manually setting the fill for all the cells to `No Color`.

Comment: I should've been more clear in my question. My sheet has five columns from column A to E. The conditional formatting rules are based on columns B and C, but the "Applies To" range is from column A to E. I think that's where my mistake is. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @cslearner88 No, that's not where your mistake is. It will still work. Try setting up a new worksheet with just the data in `B2:C7` like in my answer. Then select `A2:E7`, with `A2` the active cell, and enter the following for the conditional formatting formula: `=AND($B2>500,SEARCH("A",$C2)=1)`. Then enter any of the solutions in the answer in any cell, for example, `{=SUM((B2:B50>500)*(LEFT(C2:C50,1)="A"))}` in `G4`. If you get a zero, you forgot to array enter the formula. PS I've added a non array entered alternative, and an explanation for the array entered version to my answer.